# Batch Processing in Oracle SOA

Tags: spring, spring-batch, soa

I want to implement batch processing in Oracle SOA application. In our BPEL proceess, I will receive huge xml and I will parse xml and call other web services in each item in the XML? Oracle SOA can do it ? Or I need frameworks like Spring Batch. ?

Thanks

Comment: One can use File Debatching in the File Adapter and set the Audit Trail to None/Minimal if thats the only choice. However, it is purely a bad design to do so. One should prefer ODI or other ETL tools for very large files

Answer (score 2):

It is a very old question.But I thought I should post an answer to this.

It depends how big is your XML. If its too big then you should use something like this.
File adapter-> OSB-> SOA

As it is not recommended to use large XMLs calling BPEL directly. It will become slow as BPEL is stateful. You should rather parse the Large message using OSB then call a SOA service.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You receive the data by files?

see:

- http://blogs.oracle.com/reynolds/2007/06/batch_processing_with_bpel.html
- http://blogs.oracle.com/reynolds/2008/06/more_on_batch_processing_in_bp.html
- http://pillais.wordpress.com/2007/12/02/batch-processing-using-oracle-bpel/

or [google on "oracle bpel batch"](http://www.google.com/search?q=oracle+bpel+batch), you will find some good results